# Flickering screen after update

Tags: flicker

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.10 64bit then did apt-get update and upgrade. Then installed audio and video codecs. Since then the screen flickers whenever it has to render new pixels.

System
Motherboard: Intel DZ77SL-50K
CPU: Intel i5-3570 3.4GZ
RAM: 8GB
GPU: Radeon HD 7770 Sapphire Flex GHz Edition

How can this be fixed?

```
# lshw -c video
*-display'                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:29 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7e00000-f7e3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff

# modinfo radeon
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    ATI Radeon
author:         Gareth Hughes, Keith Whitwell, others.
depends:        drm,drm_kms_helper,ttm,i2c-algo-bit
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Comment: Which graphics driver are you using?

Comment: @AndroidDev Updated original post.